# AngularJS does not initialize input[type=range] with big numbers

Tags: angularjs, html, input, range

I have a problem binding a input[type=range] to AngularJS.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<input type="range" min="{{test.testMin}}" max="{{test.testMax}}" step="{{test.testStep}}" ng-model="test.testVal" />
```

And in my controller :

```
$scope.test = {
 testMin : 0,
 testMax : 50000,
 testVal : 10000,
 testStep : 5000
};
```

The problem is that the slider value is not initialized (0 instead of 10000).

The weird thing is that it works well with smaller values for testMax and testVal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a current AngularJS bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726

Comment: yea I end up using an other slider :-(